# Unable to find template Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, twig

В общем, не знаю, что за ерунда: но создал бандл через консоль. Захожу на страницу `/app_dev.php` и мне пишет ошибку:

> Unable to find template "TestBundle:index.html.twig" (looked into: ..\app/Resources/views, ..\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig/Resources/views/Form).

```
return $this->render('TestBundle:index.html.twig');
```

Пробовал и так

> TestBundle::index.html.twig
>
> TestBundle\index.html.twig
>
> @TestBundle:index.html.twig

Ничего не помогает, в чем может быть проблема?

[image: Скриншот дерева файлов бандла]

Answer (score 2):

В [документации](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/templating.html#referencing-templates-in-a-bundle) написано, что нужно использовать слэши `/` и не использовать слово `Bundle`.

Таким образом получаем

```
@Test/index.html.twig
```